# Each atom of the measure μ is equivalent to a singleton.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove the following theorem from A Course in Functional Analysis and
Measure Theory by Kadets:

**Theorem:**
*Suppose $X$ is a separable metric space, the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ contains all
the Borel sets, and $\mu$ is a countably additive measure on $\mathscr{A}$. Then each atom of the measure $\mu$ is equivalent to a singleton.*

That it is equivalent to a singleton means that there exists $x\in X$ such that $\mu(A\triangle \{x\}) = 0$
Under this, since $A$ is an atom and $A\setminus {x}\subseteq A$ then $\mu(A\setminus \{x\}) = 0$,and ${x}\setminus A \subseteq \{x\}$ then $\mu(\{x\}\setminus A) = 0$. This proves that they are equivalent

Sounds like no to me, but does this prove the theorem? If not, can you help me?

Comment: What is an atom?

Comment: An atom of the measure $\mu$ is a set $A\in \mathscr{A}$ with the property that
$\mu(A) > 0$ and for any $B\in \sigma (A)$ either $\mu(B) = 0$, or  $\mu(A \setminus B) = 0$

Comment: What is $\sigma(A)$? It seems to me that an atom will almost always reduce to a point. I mean, I think an "atom" in your context is an unbreakable measurable set with positive measure (that is, if $B$ is a measurable subset of an atom, then either $B$ is the atom or else it's the empty set). By the way, I only ever encountered the definition of atom to refer to a point with positive mass.

Comment: You already assume that an atom is equivalent in your argument; so it is not a proof.

Comment: @WilliamM. Here is an example of an atom that is not concentrated on a point: Let $\Omega$ be uncountable and let $\Sigma$ be the $\sigma$-algebra consisting of countable sets and sets with countable complement. Let $\mu$ be the probability measure that assigns measure zero to countable sets and measure $1$ to sets with countable complement. Then $\Omega$ itself is an atom, but no singleton is.

Comment: I found the definition of atom given [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Atom#Measure_algebras) to be helpful in understanding this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=A_0$ be an atom. Use the separability of $X$ to cover $X$ with countably many measurable sets of diameter at most $1$. The intersection of $A$ and one of these sets must have the same measure as $A$, call this intersection $A_1$. Cover $X$ with countably many measurable sets of diameter at most $1/2$. The intersection of $A_1$ and one of these measurable sets must have the same measure as $A_1=A_0=A$. Call this intersection $A_2$- Proceed this way to get a decreasing sequence $\langle A_n\rangle$ of subsets of $A$ that have the same measure as $A$ and whose diameter converges to zero. Since their diameter converges to zero, the intersection contains at most one point. Since measures are downward continuous, the intersection must have the same measure as $A$. So the intersection contains a single point in $A$ with the same measure as $A$.

Comment: You should say that the intersection has positive measure and as such it cannot be empty. I am still unsure what definition of atom OP uses for if such a definition amounts to a point, then I don't get it

Comment: I found the definition of atom given [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Atom#Measure_algebras) to be helpful in understanding this problem.

Comment: To elaborate on this answer a bit.  Since $X$ is a metric space, $X$ is Hausdorff, and so one-point sets are closed.  As such, the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ (which contains all the Borel sets and so all the closed sets) contains all the one-point sets. Thus, if $A$ is atomic and $\{x\} \subseteq A,\;$ then $A\triangle \{x\}=A\setminus\{x\}\subset A$.  Hence either $\mu(A\triangle \{x\})=0$ or $\mu(A\triangle \{x\})=\mu(A)$.  With separability (and @Michael Greinecker's argument above), we can conclude there is one $\{x\}\subseteq A$ for which $\mu(A\triangle \{x\})=0$.